# Unity3D: How to add rib to model (ex. to simple cube)

Tags: unity-game-engine, modeling

CATIA and other viewers have different view of objects - object has black ribs and it is more visible then without it.
Can I add ribs on models in Unity3D?

CATIA

[image: CATIA Cube]

Unity3D

[image: Unity3D Cube]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Import Standard asset in Unity
2. You will see Effects\ImageEffects\Scripts\EdgeDetection.cs
3. Attach this script to your camera
4. Set the mode as follows:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Good luck!

Comment: This is it!
I think, I have newer version of Unity3D and standard assets too, so it needed to import PostEffectsBase.cs and EdgeDetectNormals.shader files, but it worked.
Thanks!